# Uppercase or lowercase letters in GUIDs in the Windows Installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer

There is requirement in some tutorials about windows installer that "letters in GUIDs in the Windows Installer are always upper-case".

Is it up-to-date requirement?
What is wrong with lowercase letters in GUIDs?

Comment: As long as WiX is your only tool for creating installation packages, you should not care about upper/lower case: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/generate_guids.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been some obscure bugs if the guids are not uppercase in the MSI file. They get searched for on the system and in MSI files and some of those searches were case-sensitive, and maybe still are.

As it says here, for example, letters in ProductCode must be uppercase:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370854(v=vs.85).aspx

and here for Component Ids in uppercase:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368007(v=vs.85).aspx